# Return a pretty error json for rest api

Tags: java, json, rest, exception, error-handling

When an error occurs in my Java based rest web service
I get the exception sent to the client like this

```
 type Exception report

message Invalid Token

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Invalid Token
    com.resource.security.TokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(TokenAuthenticationFilter.java:220)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:208)
    com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:271)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.23 logs.
```

But I wanted to return a response like this

```
{
"code" : 500,
"message" : "invalid token"
}
```

How can this be done ?

**UPDATE**

```
@Provider
   public class MyApplicationExceptionHandler implements
    ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException> {

@Override
public Response toResponse(WebApplicationException weException) {

    // get initial response
    Response response = weException.getResponse();
    // create custom error
    ErrorDTO error = new ErrorDTO();
    error.setCode(response.getStatus());
    error.setMessage(weException.getMessage());
    // return the custom error
    return Response.status(response.getStatus()).entity(error).build();
}
```

}

**Web.xml**

```
  <context-param>
       <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
       <param-value>com.madzz.common.exception.MadzzApplicationExceptionHandler</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

**Application code:**

```
public String getTrackingDetailById(long orderItemId) throws Exception {
 throw new NotFoundException("not found"); }
```

I am using java.ws.rs.NotFoundException . But it doesn't seem to work.
Anypointer why?

Comment: just catch the exception and return ur own code...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the @ControllerAdvice . The logic is as follows:

You create a class with annotation where each method inside that class responds to one or more exceptions. Example here:

```
        @ControllerAdvice
    public class MyExceptionHandler {

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyExceptionHandler.class);
        @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
@ResponseBody
        public ExcObject handleSQLException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex){
            logger.info("SQLException Occured:: URL="+request.getRequestURL());
            return "database_error";
        }

        @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="IOException occured")
        @ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
        public void handleIOException(){
            logger.error("IOException handler executed");
            //returning 404 error code
        }
    }
```

Inside the handleSQLException construct your newly created object of the newly created class ExcObject and return this.

In your controller you need to throw the specific exception.

Pay attention also that you need to create MyCustomException which will extend exception.

Comment: Thanks all . Got samples from this link. https://github.com/Codingpedia/demo-rest-jersey-spring   http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/error-handling-in-rest-api-with-jersey/

Answer (score 0):

Use you own exception handler:

```
try {
   ...you code that throws AuthenticationServiceException
} catch (AuthenticationServiceException ex) {
   ... return you custom JSONObject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch all exceptions at the base level, and convert to JSON, then return the JSON representation of the exception, wit a return code of 400.   Below is the routine to convert an Exception to JSON in a standardized way:

```
public static JSONObject convertToJSON(Throwable e, String context) throws Exception {
    JSONObject responseBody = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject errorTag = new JSONObject();
    responseBody.put("error", errorTag);

    errorTag.put("code", 400);
    errorTag.put("context", context);

    JSONArray detailList = new JSONArray();
    errorTag.put("details", detailList);

    Throwable nextRunner = e;
    List<ExceptionTracer> traceHolder = new ArrayList<ExceptionTracer>();
    while (nextRunner!=null) {
        Throwable runner = nextRunner;
        nextRunner = runner.getCause();

        detailObj.put("code", runner.getClass().getName());
        String msg =  runner.toString();
        detailObj.put("message",msg);

        detailList.put(detailObj);
    }

    JSONArray stackList = new JSONArray();
    for (StackTraceElement ste : e.getStackTrace()) {
        ja.put(ste.getFileName() + ": " + ste.getMethodName()
               + ": " + ste.getLineNumber());
    }
    errorTag.put("stack", stackList);

    return responseBody;
}
```

You can find the complete open source library that implements this at:  [Mendocino JSON Utilities](https://github.com/agilepro/mendocino/blob/master/src/com/purplehillsbooks/json/JSONObject.java).   This library supports the JSON Objects as well as the exceptions.

This produces a JSON structure of this form:

```
{
   "error": {
      "code": "400",
      "message": "main error message here",
      "target": "approx what the error came from",
      "details": [
         {
            "code": "23-098a",
            "message": "Disk drive has frozen up again.  It needs to be replaced",
            "target": "not sure what the target is"
         }
      ],
      "innererror": {
         "trace": [ ... ],
         "context": [ ... ]
      }
   }
}
```

This is the format proposed by the OASIS data standard [OASIS OData](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/errata02/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-errata02-os-complete.html#_Toc403940655) and seems to be the most standard option out there, however there does not seem to be high adoption rates of any standard at this point.

The details are discussed in my blog post on [Error Handling in JSON REST API](https://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/json-rest-api-exception-handling/)